# Prove, that for any A, B, C sets, $A\times (B\setminus C) = (A\times B)\setminus (A\times C)$ is true.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have to prove the equation 
$$A\times (B\setminus C) = (A\times B)\setminus (A\times C)$$
knowing that
$$A\times B = \{<a,b> |\: a\in A \wedge b\in B\}$$
which I attempted to do the following way:
Let's take any x.
Then $x\in A\times (B\setminus C)$ iff 
$$(\exists a\in A)\: (\exists b\in (B\setminus C))\: (x=<a,b>)$$
$$\equiv \exists a\exists b \:(a\in A) \wedge (b \in B \:\wedge b \notin C) \:\wedge x=<a,b>$$
$$\equiv \exists a\exists b \: (a \in A\: \wedge b \in B\: \wedge x=<a,b>) \: \wedge (a\in A\: \wedge b\notin C\: \wedge x=<a,b>)$$
Further transformations lead me to $(A\times B) \times(A\setminus C)$, which is not the thing I was meant to prove. I need an advice how should I do it the right way, because I cannot find any solution.

Comment: *NB:* $A\setminus C\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should have written is $$(a,\,b)\in A\times (B\backslash C)\iff a\in A\land b\in B\land b\not\in C\\\iff (a\in A\land b\in B)\land\neg(a\in A\land b\in C)\\\iff (a,\,b)\in (A\times B)\backslash (A\times C).$$

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail what has exactly happened in 2nd line, that you could negate it? I do not understand the part that $a\in A \wedge b\notin C$ turned into $\neg (a\in A \wedge b\in C)$.

Comment: @whiskey0 We've rewritten $b\not\in C$ as $\neg (b\in C)$, then included within the argument of $\neg$ a true statement conjoined by $\land$ to the original $b\in C$. This doesn't change the truth value, but it obtains $(a,\,b)\not\in A\times C$ as the final second half.